# DrawString across multiple JPanels within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, drawstring

I've got `somePanel1`, `somePanel2`, and `somePanel3` instantiated within `someFrame`.

If I do a `drawString` in `somePanel` form, how can I get the output to be different in `somePanel1`, `somePanel2`, and `somePanel3`.

For instance `g.drawString("X", x, y);` puts an `X` in all three `somePanel`s. How do I get:

- `somePanel1` to output `X`,
- `somePanel2` to output `Y`, and
- `somePanel3` to output `Z`?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments `SomePanel` is auto-generated. You could simple add a setter method to allow the message to be changed:

```
class SomePanel extends JPanel {

   // message to be used in drawString
   private String message;

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }
  ...
}
```

then use

```
somePanel1.setMessage("X");
...
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have.  I guess what I'm really asking is how do I "instantiate passing `X`, `Y`, `Z`"?

Comment: Sorry for belaboring the point but, somePanel1 was auto created in the someFrame form... 

`private main somePanel somePanel1;`

So I can't use that in the somePane form. If I use 

`somePanel1 = new SomePanel("X");` 

in someFrame I get a cannot find symbol error

Comment: I meant `private Main.somePanel somePanel1;`

Comment: ...`somePanel` is placed in `someFrame` three times so `someFrame` auto-generates `somePanel1`, `somePanel2`, and `somePanel3`. If I type in `somePanel1.` within `someFrame` source, the only pop-up option I get is `new`.

Comment: I would recommend coding by hand here. It would not only give you greater freedom to add constructor args but you would get more familiar with the code itself :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I guess unless I show you all of my code, it's hard to understand what is going on.